How does Linux handle multiple sockets bound to the same port with `INADDR_ANY` and a specific IP address?
I'm developing a server application on Linux and have a question about socket binding behavior when using INADDR_ANY and specific IP addresses. My test setup involves two sockets:

One socket bound to port 80 with INADDR_ANY, meaning it listens on all available IP addresses.
Another socket bound to port 80 on a specific IP address, 192.168.1.4.

My question is:

If a client attempts to connect to 192.168.1.4 on port 80, is there any possibility that the connection could be handled by the socket bound to INADDR_ANY instead of the one explicitly bound to 192.168.1.4?

I am also using the SO_REUSEPORT socket option on both sockets. Could this affect how the connections are routed, or is it purely related to allowing both sockets to bind to the same port without error?


Here is the relevant snippet of how I'm binding the sockets:
// Test Program //

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main() {
    int sock1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    int sock2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    int optval = 1;
    setsockopt(sock1, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &optval, sizeof(optval));
    setsockopt(sock2, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &optval, sizeof(optval));

    // Socket 1: Bind to INADDR_ANY (all interfaces)
    struct sockaddr_in addr1;
    addr1.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr1.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    addr1.sin_port = htons(80);
    if (bind(sock1, (struct sockaddr*)&addr1, sizeof(addr1)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed for sock1");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Socket 2: Bind to specific IP address
    struct sockaddr_in addr2;
    addr2.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr2.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.4");
    addr2.sin_port = htons(80);
    if (bind(sock2, (struct sockaddr*)&addr2, sizeof(addr2)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed for sock2");
        exit(1);
    }

    int rval1 = listen(sock1, 5);
    if (rval1 == -1) {
        perror("listen failed for sock1");
        exit(1);
    }

    int rval2 = listen(sock2, 5);
    if (rval2 == -1) {
        perror("listen failed for sock2");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("%s\n", "Exiting test program");
}

What I've Learned So Far:

The socket bound to INADDR_ANY listens on all available IPs, while the other socket only listens on 192.168.1.4.
The SO_REUSEPORT option allows both sockets to bind to the same port without errors, but as far as I understand, it doesn’t control which socket handles incoming connections.

My Key Questions:

Is there any scenario where a connection targeting 192.168.1.4:80 could be handled by the INADDR_ANY socket?
What role does SO_REUSEPORT play here? Does it impact which socket handles incoming connections, or is it only relevant during the binding process?

Desired Behavior:
I want to ensure that any connections targeting 192.168.1.4:80 are always handled by the second socket (the one explicitly bound to that address), and connections to other IPs (e.g., 127.0.0.1:80) are handled by the INADDR_ANY socket.
Any clarification or confirmation of how Linux handles this would be greatly appreciated!

Use one socket and check the peer IP after accept.

If you wanted to accept connection on any of listening sockets, you could use SO_REUSEPORT. But it's not the case, as i understand. For your desired behavior you can listen on 66.117.236.114 on some another port and redirect incomping connections there with firewall, depending on destination address.

@dimich SO_REUSEPORT is probably the option i was looking for. I do want to allow connections on any of the listening sockets, but make sure that the sockets with specific IP addresses are prioritized over sockets with INADDR_ANY. If that's not the case then @MarcoBonelli suggestion is probably the solution.

I edited my question so it uses the proper option flag and updated the code for anyone interested in answering.

The SO_REUSEADDR option on TCP sockets only allows you to listen/bind a port if there's an outstanding connection from a prior run of the program that hasn't yet fully closed.  It doesn't actually allow you to have multiple listening sockets open on the same IP/port.
The code above binds the sockets, but you haven't yet attempted to listen on either one.  If you attempt to do so:
rval = listen(sock1, 5);
if (rval==-1) {
    perror("listen failed for sock1");
    exit(1);
}
rval = listen(sock2, 5);
if (rval==-1) {
    perror("listen failed for sock2");
    exit(1);
}

One of them will fail:
listen failed for sock2: Address already in use

You should only have one listening socket bound to INADDR_ANY, as that will handle any incoming connection on port 80, regardless of the interface.

You explained why the OP's approach wouldn't work, but could you add the solution to the OP's problem (using one socket and checking the peer's address) to your answer (i.e. actually provide an answer to Key Question 1)?

As explained in @dbush's answer,
you can only have one single socket listening on one address, even if you use INADDR_ANY. So the only possible way is to have one single listening socket, and on INADD_ANY. But after each successful accept, you can control what was the requested address with getsockname:
struct sockaddr_in addr1;
addr1.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr1.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
addr1.sin_port = htons(80);
if (bind(sock1, (struct sockaddr*)&addr1, sizeof(addr1)) < 0) {
    perror("bind failed for sock1");
    exit(1);
}

int rval1 = listen(sock1, 5);
if (rval1 == -1) {
    perror("listen failed for sock1");
    exit(1);
}

for (;;) {
struct sockaddr_in locaddr, remaddr;
int addrlen;
int rval = accept(s, (struct sockaddr*) & remaddr, &socklen);
if (rval == -1) {
    perror("accept failed");
    exit(1);
}
in rval = getsockname(c, (struct sockaddr*) & locaddr, &socklen)) {
if (rval == -1) {
    perror("getsockname failed");
    exit(1);
}
// locaddr now contains either 192.168.1.4 or not, so can can choose
// which branch to use...


You did not mention SO_REUSEPORT. It allows multiple sockets to listen on the same port as long as the IP address specified is different. I have tested this myself. I am currently working on test server and client programs and will post my findings unless someone else can provide a good answer to my question.

I created 2 test programs, a server and client. They will do 100 test connections spread between all IP addresses passed as arguments.
According to my tests, Linux does indeed prioritize sockets with a specified IP address when using SO_REUSEPORT, although more testing with different IP addresses is needed. I would still like to see some kind of documentation or actual kernel code proving this.
Server code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_IP_ADDRESSES 8

#define MAX_IP_LENGTH 64
#define HASH_SIZE 100

// Struct to store IP address and connection count
struct ip_entry {
    char ip[MAX_IP_LENGTH];
    int count;
};

// Thread function argument structure
struct thread_data {
    int sock;  // Socket for the thread
    int thread_id;  // Thread identifier
    const char* ip_address; // The IP address the thread is listening to
    struct ip_entry ip_table[HASH_SIZE]; // Hash table to store IP connections
    int connection_count;  // Number of connections handled by this thread
};

// Shared connection counter
volatile int shared_connection_count = 0;
pthread_mutex_t count_mutex;

// Hash function for IP addresses
unsigned int hash(const char *ip) {
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    while (*ip) {
        hash = (hash << 5) + *ip++;
    }
    return hash % HASH_SIZE;
}

// Function to update the IP connection count in the hash table
void update_ip_count(const char *ip_str, struct thread_data *data) {
    unsigned int index = hash(ip_str);

    // Linear probing in case of hash collision
    while (strlen(data->ip_table[index].ip) > 0 && strcmp(data->ip_table[index].ip, ip_str) != 0) {
        index = (index + 1) % HASH_SIZE;
    }

    // If the entry is new, store the IP
    if (strlen(data->ip_table[index].ip) == 0) {
        strncpy(data->ip_table[index].ip, ip_str, MAX_IP_LENGTH);
        data->ip_table[index].count = 1;
    } else {
        data->ip_table[index].count++;
    }
}

// Function to detect the local protocol address (IP address) associated with a socket and update its count
void detect_connection_ip(int client_socket, struct thread_data *data) {
    struct sockaddr_in local_address;
    socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(local_address);

    // Get the local IP address the connection was made on
    if (getsockname(client_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&local_address, &addr_len) == 0) {
        char ip_str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &local_address.sin_addr, ip_str, sizeof(ip_str));

        // Update the IP connection count
        update_ip_count(ip_str, data);
    } else {
        perror("getsockname failed");
    }
}

// Function to print the connection counts for each IP address
void print_ip_table(struct thread_data *data) {
    for (int i = 0; i < HASH_SIZE; i++) {
        if (strlen(data->ip_table[i].ip) > 0) {
            printf("IP: %s, Connections: %d\n", data->ip_table[i].ip, data->ip_table[i].count);
        }
    }
    printf("%s", "\n");
}

// Function that each thread will run
void *socket_thread(void *arg) {
    struct thread_data *data = (struct thread_data *)arg;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    socklen_t client_len = sizeof(client_addr);

    while (true) {
        // Accept connections
        int client_sock = accept(data->sock, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &client_len);
        if (client_sock < 0) {
            if (shared_connection_count >= 100) {
                break;
            }
            if (errno != EAGAIN) {
                perror("accept failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            continue;
        }

        detect_connection_ip(client_sock, data);

        // Increment the connection counter for this thread
        data->connection_count++;

        // Increment the shared connection counter in a thread-safe manner
        pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
        shared_connection_count++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);

        // Wait for the client to close the connection (dont do this in the real world!)
        char buffer[8]; // dummy buffer
        while (true) {
            ssize_t bytesRecv = recv(client_sock, buffer, 8, 0);
            if (bytesRecv == 0) {
                // Client closed the connection
                break;
            } else if (bytesRecv < 0) {
                // No data, but try again
                if (errno != EAGAIN) {
                    perror("recv failed");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }
        }

        // Close the client socket
        close(client_sock);
    }

    // Close the listening socket when done
    close(data->sock);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

// Function to enable or disbale socket blocking
int set_socket_blocking_enabled(int fd, bool blocking) {
    if (fd < 0) return -1;

    int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
    flags = blocking ? (flags & ~O_NONBLOCK) : (flags | O_NONBLOCK);
    return fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags);
}

// Function to create a listening socket given a port & address
int create_socket(int port, const char *address) {
    int s;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    // Create a new socket
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (s < 0) {
        perror("unable to create socket");
        return -1;
    }

    int optval = 1;
    // Set socket options to reuse port
    if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &optval, sizeof(optval)) < 0) {
        perror("setsockopt failed for SO_REUSEPORT on socket");
        return -1;
    }

    // Set to non-blocking
    if (set_socket_blocking_enabled(s, false) < 0) {
        perror("failed to disbale blocking for socket");
        return -1;
    }

    // Bind to socket with IP address
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    if (address == NULL) {
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    } else {
        if ((strlen(address) == 0) ||
        (strcmp("INADDR_ANY", address) == 0)) {
            addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        } else {
            addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(address);
        }
    }
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed for socket");
        return -1;
    }

    // Start listening on the socket
    if (listen(s, 25) < 0) {
        perror("listen failed for socket");
        return -1;
    }

    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int port = 0;
    const char *ip_addresses[MAX_IP_ADDRESSES];
    int ip_count = 0;

    // Argument parsing
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-p") == 0 && i + 1 < argc) {
            port = atoi(argv[++i]);
        } else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-ip") == 0 && i + 1 < argc) {
            if (ip_count < MAX_IP_ADDRESSES) {
                ip_addresses[ip_count++] = argv[++i];
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Too many IP addresses specified. Max allowed is %d.\n", MAX_IP_ADDRESSES);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }

    // Check if port and at least one IP address are specified
    if (port == 0 || ip_count == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s -p <PORT> -ip <IP_ADDRESS> [-ip <IP_ADDRESS> ...]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Initialize the mutex
    pthread_mutex_init(&count_mutex, NULL);

    // Thread and socket arrays
    pthread_t threads[MAX_IP_ADDRESSES];
    struct thread_data thread_data_array[MAX_IP_ADDRESSES];

    // Create sockets and threads for each IP address
    for (int i = 0; i < ip_count; i++) {
        const char *ip_address = ip_addresses[i];
        int sock = create_socket(port, ip_address);
        if (sock < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create socket for %s\n", ip_address);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // Set up thread data
        memset(&thread_data_array[i], 0, sizeof(struct thread_data));
        thread_data_array[i].sock = sock;
        thread_data_array[i].thread_id = i + 1;
        thread_data_array[i].ip_address = ip_address;

        // Create thread
        if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, socket_thread, &thread_data_array[i]) != 0) {
            perror("pthread_create failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    // Tell the user that the server is listening
    printf("Listening for connections on %d IP addresses\n\n", ip_count);

    // Wait for all threads to finish
    for (int i = 0; i < ip_count; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    // Destroy the mutex
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&count_mutex);

    // Print final connection counts
    for (int i = 0; i < ip_count; i++) {
        printf("Thread %d listening to %s handled %d connections\n",
        thread_data_array[i].thread_id,
        thread_data_array[i].ip_address,
        thread_data_array[i].connection_count);
        print_ip_table(&thread_data_array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

Client Code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_IP_ADDRESSES 8
#define TOTAL_THREADS 100

typedef struct {
    const char *ip_address;
    int port;
} thread_args_t;

void *connect_to_server(void *args) {
    thread_args_t *thread_args = (thread_args_t *)args;
    const char *ip_address = thread_args->ip_address;
    int port = thread_args->port;
    int client_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    // Generate a random sleep time between 1 and 2000 ms
    int sleep_time = (rand() % 2000) + 1;
    usleep(sleep_time * 1000);  // Convert milliseconds to microseconds for usleep

    // Create a socket
    client_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (client_sock < 0) {
        perror("Failed to create socket");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    // Set up the server address structure
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_address);

    // Attempt to connect to the server
    if (connect(client_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("Connection failed");
        close(client_sock);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    printf("Connected to %s on port %d after sleeping %d ms\n", ip_address, port, sleep_time);

    // Generate a random sleep time between 1 and 2000 ms
    sleep_time = (rand() % 2000) + 1;
    usleep(sleep_time * 1000);  // Convert milliseconds to microseconds for usleep

    // Close the connection
    close(client_sock);

    printf("Closed connection to %s on port %d after sleeping %d ms\n", ip_address, port, sleep_time);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int port = 0;
    int ip_count = 0;
    const char *ip_addresses[MAX_IP_ADDRESSES];  // Array to store up to 8 IP addresses

    // Parse command line arguments
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-p") == 0 && i + 1 < argc) {
            port = atoi(argv[++i]);
        } else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-ip") == 0 && i + 1 < argc) {
            if (ip_count < MAX_IP_ADDRESSES) {
                ip_addresses[ip_count++] = argv[++i];
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "A maximum of %d IP addresses is supported.\n", MAX_IP_ADDRESSES);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }

    if (port == 0 || ip_count == 0) {
        printf("Usage: %s -p <PORT> -ip <IP_ADDRESS> [-ip <IP_ADDRESS> ...] (up to %d IP addresses)\n",
        argv[0], MAX_IP_ADDRESSES);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Seed the random number generator
    srand(time(NULL));

    pthread_t threads[TOTAL_THREADS];
    thread_args_t args[TOTAL_THREADS];

    // Create 100 threads, cycling through the available IP addresses
    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_THREADS; i++) {
        args[i].ip_address = ip_addresses[i % ip_count];  // Cycle through IPs
        args[i].port = port;

        if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, connect_to_server, &args[i]) != 0) {
            perror("Failed to create thread");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    // Wait for all threads to finish
    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    printf("Client test completed.\n");
    return 0;
}

Compile
gcc server.c -o server -Wall
gcc client.c -o client -Wall

Run test server:
sudo ./server -p 80 -ip 192.168.1.4 -ip INADDR_ANY

or
sudo ./server -p 80 -ip INADDR_ANY -ip 192.168.1.4

Run test client:
sudo ./client -p 80 -ip 192.168.1.4 -ip 127.1.1.0

